# Malloc fails when the input size exceeds 10

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I'm allocating memory using malloc but fails when the input size becomes more than 10 why is this happening ?

I am also giving code and error message:

#### error message

> Solution: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

#### code

```
int birthdayCakeCandles(int candles_count, int* candles) {

 int temp,i,flag=1;
for (i=1;i<=candles_count;i++){
  if(candles[0]<candles[i]) {
      temp=candles[0];
      candles[0]=candles[i];
      candles[i]=temp;
  }
 else if(candles[0]==candles[i]){
      flag=flag+1;
  }
}
return flag;
}

int main()
{   int candles_count,i;
scanf("%d",&candles_count);
   int *candles= (int*)malloc(candles_count*sizeof(int));
   for(i=0;i<candles_count;i++){
     scanf("%d",(candles+i));  
   }

    int result = birthdayCakeCandles(candles_count, candles);
    printf("%d",result);
    free(candles);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i=1;i<=candles_count;i++)` That overflows the buffer. On the last iteration `i` has the value `candles_count` which is not a valid index for the array. Looks like it should be `for (i=1;i<candles_count;i++)`

Comment: thanks for the help it really worked !! so was this happening because i was using an" i "value that does not points to a memory location?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not clearly written. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

in line number 4 you are starting from index 1 and cheking till index N(<= sign) where N is non index term and your are reading memory from the region where you are not allowed.